# How can I change elements with pyscript?

Tags: pyscript

I want to make a button change color with pyscript. This code doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/releases/2023.11.1/core.css" />
    <script type="module" src="https://pyscript.net/releases/2023.11.1/core.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button  id="run" py-click="colorChange()">CLICK</button>

    </div>
    <style>
        #run{ background-color: rgb(61, 139, 130)}
    </style>
    <py-script>
        from js import document
```

type here

```
        runButton=document.getElementById("run")
        def colorChange(event):
            runButton.setAttribute("style", "background-color:red")
    </py-script>
</body>
</html>
```

Someone could help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for `py-event` attributes [changed in the 2023.11.1 release](https://jeff.glass/post/whats-new-pyscript-2023-11-1/#events-are-different). Rather than being a string of executable code, they're just the name of a Callable in the global namespace.

So `py-click="colorChange()"` should be `py-click="colorChange"`.